# Design help for serialized classes that need database access

Tags: 8, database, dependency-injection, symfony-services

I want to convert from `\Drupal::database()` to dependency injection.

I'm not 100% certain how to move forward with a refactor I know I have to complete.  Currently I have a series of custom classes that implements a `Callback` interface of mine. They do whatever the respective callback requires.  These callbacks are stored serialized in some `QueueManager` (database, rabbitmq, etc).

At some point in the future the `QueueManager` will grab a callback from the queue, inflate it and issue the interface contract for the `Callback` to do its work.  The catch is the callback needs access to the database.

Now I currently have them built in such a way that they use the `\Drupal::database()` method to access the database (because they get serialized), but I want to use the more acceptable and better approach of dependency injection.  I'm not 100% certain how to go about doing this; because I cannot serialize a database connection.

I know that the `QueueManager` class will most likely become a Drupal service, but I don't know how to handle the database dependency on the serialized callbacks.

Comment: You can't serialize the database connection, but you can unset/set it on `__sleep` and `__wakeup` respectively...how exactly that plays with an injected DB service on `__wakeup` I'm not sure. Good question

Comment: Thought it sounded familiar, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238217/when-should-i-use-dependencyserializationtrait. You should be able to inject the service as normal, save a reference to it as a property on the class, add `use DependencySerializationTrait;` to that class, and Drupal will take care of the `__sleep` and `__wakeup` magic for you

Comment: @Clive, that is correct, Drupal's db service isn't serializeable, this was the basis for my question (just not explicitly stated).  For the DIC-hell, so will I just set some class variable in `Callback` that has the string of the service name and then use that as an abstraction?  Follow up: I was reading the documentation for Drupal's `Connection` class -- I don't see where I can get the service ID from that class.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you implement the trait you don't need to do that manually; the trait's `__sleep` method runs through all relevant properties on the class and replaces their value with the service ID, and the `__wakeup` method restores them automatically. You're not missing anything, the database service is injected and the connection comes from the `getConnection()` method, so you might need to add a helper method that returns `$this->database->getConnection()`, and refer to that in your own code rather than using `$this->connection` or similar directly. Slightly awkward but at least it gets the job done

Comment: Just re-read your comment and I missed the point a bit, sorry. Drupal overrides the container and adds a public `_serviceId` property to all injected services to allow this all to work. You won't see it in the service class definition itself, it's added by [`Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container::get`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21DependencyInjection%21Container.php/function/Container%3A%3Aget/8.4.x). Your callback will have access to it via `$this->serviceName->_serviceId`